# Flutter & Dart ERROR : import 'package:flutter_iconpicker/flutter_iconpicker.dart';

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a Future ( **Selecting Icon** ) so I have used this package:

```
import 'package:flutter_iconpicker/flutter_iconpicker.dart';
```

I used this as the source [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_iconpicker/install) even in a new project this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_iconpicker/flutter_iconpicker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Icon? _icon;

  _pickIcon() async {
    IconData? icon = await FlutterIconPicker.showIconPicker(context,
        iconPackModes: [IconPack.cupertino]);

    _icon = Icon(icon);
    setState(() {});

    debugPrint('Picked Icon:  $icon');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _pickIcon,
              child: const Text('Open IconPicker'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              child: _icon ?? Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and it shows these errors:

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_iconpicker-3.1.4+1/lib/IconPicker/Packs/Material.dart:1230:25: Error: Member not found: 'class__sharp'.
  'class__sharp': Icons.class__sharp,
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_iconpicker-3.1.4+1/lib/IconPicker/Packs/Material.dart:1231:27: Error: Member not found: 'class__rounded'.
  'class__rounded': Icons.class__rounded,
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_iconpicker-3.1.4+1/lib/IconPicker/Packs/Material.dart:1232:28: Error: Member not found: 'class__outlined'.
  'class__outlined': Icons.class__outlined,
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_iconpicker-3.1.4+1/lib/IconPicker/iconPicker.dart:47:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                   ^
3

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Even if it will not show anything on the emulator the above code is the example of the source that I mentioned above and it was not working
and I went according to the instructions that he describes in section ([installing](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_iconpicker/install)) and still not working, Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_iconpicker/install) needs to be upgraded!

Solution:If you don't use/need those three icons
you can remove/comment those three icons from you local c drive path shown in error.

And add null check operator (!) to the error line shown in error.

Note: Making local changes in plugin will make app run in your end,if you share code they needs to do the above step to run the app

Thanks!!

Comment: I did what you told me, and I fixed three of the above problems, but the fourth one I couldn't find it, but now it's better and shows it on emulator.

thanks for helping : )

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with [`flutter_iconpicker`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_iconpicker) and the new Flutter version 3.0.

There is an open issue with a workaround in [the official repository issues](https://github.com/Ahmadre/FlutterIconPicker/issues/47#issuecomment-1140494881). Transcripted below:

> open `YOUR_PC/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_iconpicker-3.1.4+1/lib/IconPicker/Packs/Material.dart` file and search and comment the lines that contains,
> class_sharp, class_rounded, class_outlined and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

I have raised a pull request to fix the package and remove references to icons that are no longer there in different icon packs that this library uses: https://github.com/Ahmadre/FlutterIconPicker/pull/57

Meanwhile, you can use my version of this library until the repo owners merge the fixes: https://github.com/rasulf/FlutterIconPicker/tree/remove-whatsapp-material-icons-ref

In your pub spec.yaml, just change how you define the dependency like this:

```
flutter_iconpicker:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/rasulf/FlutterIconPicker
    ref: remove-whatsapp-material-icons-ref
```